# What is YSSegmentedControl

Tags: swift, xcode

I have SegmentedControl with 3 segments.Could you please help me to change my SegmentedControl as shown in figure.I am new to Xcode . I don't know what YSSegmentedControl is.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yemeksepeti/YSSegmentedControl/master/demo.gif

Comment: Do you know how to use pods?

Comment: Download the github sample project and you have everything. What else do you need? https://github.com/yemeksepeti/YSSegmentedControl

Comment: I don't know to use pods.I need to use it in my project and i don't know how to add this frame in to my project

Comment: how can create  YSSegmentedControl with frame and titles after copying the YSSegmentedControl.swift flie in to my project

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step tutorial of how to install the `YSSegmentedControl` pod.

I think you probably don't have CocoaPods installed. So first do this command to install CocoaPods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Be sure to have the latest version of Ruby installed first.

After that, `cd` to the project directory. Do this command:

```
pod init
```

Now you will see a `Podfile` in your project directory.

Open and edit this Podfile. First, uncomment

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

(Your Podfile might not have '8.0' but some other number. That's fine.)

and this line as well:

```
use_frameworks!
```

Now, you will see that there is something like this:

```
target 'XXX' do

end
```

where `XXX` is your target's name.

Now change that to

```
target 'XXX' do
    pod 'YSSegmentedControl'
end
```

Remember to save.

Now close Xcode and in your project directory, do:

```
pod install
```

Wait for all the pods to install. After that, **open the xcworkspace file instead of the xcodeproj file!** This is very important. After you installed the pods, you should *always* open the `xcworkspace` file, otherwise your project can break.

Now in your project settings, the "Linked Libraries and Frameworks" section, add `YSSegmentedControl.framework`.

After rebuilding, you can follow the instructions in the README file to start using the pod!

Good luck!